# Dynamic Rsyslog template

Tags: linux, templates, logging, rsyslog

I have an Rsyslog configuration that looks like this:

```
template(name="extract" type="string" string="%msg:R:/(?:"(level)":")((\\"|

[^"])*)"/g–end%")

if $InputFileTag == 'esblog' then {
    set $!level = exec_template("extract");
} else {
    set $!level = $syslogseverity-text;
}

template(name="json_lines" type="list") {
    constant(value="{")
      constant(value="\"@timestamp\":\"")     property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339")
      constant(value="\",\"host\":\"")        property(name="hostname")
      constant(value="\",\"json.level\":\"")    property(name="$!level" format="json")
      constant(value="\",\"facility\":\"")    property(name="syslogfacility-text")
      constant(value="\",\"tag\":\"")   property(name="syslogtag" format="json")
      constant(value="\",\"message\":\"")    property(name="msg" format="json")
    constant(value="\"}")
}
```

Basically, if the source tag is esblog, I want to use this regular expression, from "extract" to pull the severity out of the log message. Otherwise I want to use the default severity. Then use that variable inside the json.level label, so that I only need one template on the outgoing message. But no luck getting this to work yet.

Sample message with RegEx: https://regex101.com/r/lN4tD4/1

**ERROR LOG**

```
0341.407068000:main thread    : error: can not find regex end in: '(?:"level":")(\"|[^"]*)"–end%'
0341.407084000:main thread    : PROP_INVALID for name ''
0341.407097000:main thread    : Called LogMsg, msg: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.conf, on or before line 32: invalid property ''
0341.407195000:main thread    : Called LogMsg, msg: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.conf, on or before line 32: error processing template object
0341.407350000:main thread    : Called LogMsg, msg: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.conf, on or before line 33: exec_template(): template 'extract'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RegEx just needed changing.

```
template(name="extract" type="string" string="%msg:R,ERE,2,DFLT:(\"level\":\")(\\\"|[^\"]*)\"--end%")


if $programname contains "esb-log" then {
    set $!level = exec_template("extract");
} else {
    set $!level = $syslogseverity-text;
}
```

Online Rsyslog RegEx tool: http://www.rsyslog.com/regex/